# Flex hide Text 2 seconds after it's shown

Tags: apache-flex, effect, visible, invisible

I have this scenario I'm trying to accomplish:
I have Text that is always on the screen, but most of the time visible is set to false. I have a handler that when an event occurs it makes this Text visible. Easy enough so far. The next requirement though, is to add an effect to this Text to make it go away 2 seconds after it appears. So essentially I need an effect to wait 2 seconds and then set visible back to false.

I've never worked with effects before in Flex though so I don't really even know where to start. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to start a Timer(2000) of 2 seconds and one the TimerEvent.Timer event to set the text field visible = false;

Update: (after 1st comment)

You can also do the following but not so nice from programming side, at the end still using a timer or something similar in the background.

```
<mx:Text
     showEffect="myHideFadeEffect"/>

<mx:FadeEffect
    id        = "myHideFadeEffect"
    alphaFrom = "1"
    alphaTo   = "0"
    startDelay= "2000"/>
```

But once again I do not recommend this approach.

Comment: Yes, I have that working though. I was wondering though if there was just an effect I could add on to the Text element itself that would do this by default every time. So I didn't have to use a Timer.

Comment: Ok thanks for the udpate. This can't be done from the ActionScript side very easily though? Then yes, I probably will stick with the Timer implementation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. You can do that for sure inside AS as well, just need to set the styles correct. But, I think using a timer is the best. :)